# Route constraint to be either "car" or "boat

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I have a route where I want to set a constraint on the "action" paramter.  It has to be either "Car" or "Boat"

Answer (score 2):

I think this should do it.

```
route.MapRoute("CarOrBoat", "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { id = 0 },
                new {action = @"Car|Boat" }
```